# Play/Pause/Stop multiple audio file which are stored locally

Tags: ios, objective-c, avqueueplayer

I have 20 audio tracks, which are stored locally in my project.

I want to play all that files sequentially . For that I have used AVQueuePlayer. Please check below code for reference.

Declaration :-

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    AVAudioPlayer *player;
    NSMutableArray *arrPlayData;
    AVPlayerItem *item;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVQueuePlayer *queuePlayer;
```

Button Clicks as below,

```
-(IBAction)click_Play:(id)sender {

            for (int j = 0; j < arrPlayData.count; j++) {
            path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[arrPlayData objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"AudioName"] ofType:@"wav"];
            item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
                 if (_queuePlayer == nil) {
                     _queuePlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];
                 } else{
                     [_queuePlayer insertItem:item afterItem:nil];
                 }
            }
        [_queuePlayer setVolume:1.0];
        [_queuePlayer play];
}
```

Then on pause button I have written below code,

```
-(IBAction)click_Pause:(id)sender {
    [_queuePlayer pause];
}
```

And on Stop button I have written below code,

```
-(IBAction)click_Stop:(id)sender {
    [_queuePlayer removeAllItems];
}
```

Everything is working well, the problem I am facing is with PAUSE button. When I click on pause button it stops playing. Then again when I click on play button it plays from the same place where I pause it. Till here everything looks good. But on playing the audio queue after pausing, it plays remaining part of audio queue and then again it plays one more time the whole audio queue. Don't know how to resolve it. Why it is playing whole audio queue again?

Anyone have idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whole audio queue is playing again because you are inserting item from `arrPlayData` every time `click_Play` is clicked.

So, in `click_Play` check count of items and handle accordingly like insert item only if count of items `_queuePlayer` is Zero.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
  BOOL FromPause;
}

-(IBAction)click_Stop:(id)sender {
    [_queuePlayer removeAllItems];
}

-(IBAction)click_Pause:(id)sender {
    [_queuePlayer pause];
    FromPause=YES;

}

-(IBAction)click_Play:(id)sender {

            for (int j = 0; j < arrPlayData.count; j++) {
            path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[arrPlayData objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"AudioName"] ofType:@"wav"];
            item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
                 if (_queuePlayer == nil) {
                     _queuePlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];
                 } else{
                     if(FromPause){
                      //don't add again
                        FromPause=NO;
                     }
                     else{
                          [_queuePlayer insertItem:item afterItem:nil];
                     }
                 }
            }
        [_queuePlayer setVolume:1.0];
        [_queuePlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of you are initialize `AVPlayerItem` again in `click_Play`.
Please take one `bool` value and insert `arrPlayData` if `AVPlayerItem` not allocated.