# Play/Pause/Stop multiple audio files simultaneously and also with sequential manner

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, sequential, simultaneous

I am working on music application,
Want to play multiple audio files simultaneously,
Found many stackoverflow links to get the solution but still no luck for my scenario,

I have total 8 arrays, In each array there are some number of audio files names.
Like,

```
array1 = @[@"aud1",@"aud2"];
array2 = @[@"aud4",@"aud5",@"aud8",@"aud11"];
....
array8 = @[@"aud3",@"aud6",@"aud7"];
```

All audio files are stored locally in my project, with .wav file extension.

Now, what I want to achieve is, all the array should play in sequential manner with simultaneous play of all audio files which is in one array. i.e. aud1, aud2 **(array1)** should play together then instantly in sequential manner aud4,aud5,aud8,aud11 **(array2)** should play simultaneously and so on..

Also I wanted to implement Pause/Stop functionality as well.
I am aware with `AVAudioPlayer`, `AVQueuePlayer`..

AVQueuePlayer works well with sequential play. I have implemented this code, [Play/Pause/Stop multiple audio file which are stored locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864687/play-pause-stop-multiple-audio-file-which-are-stored-locally) But it is not working with simultaneous play followed by sequential play.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

@Gati, have you tried GCD - Grand Central Dispatch? I think it could be the solution for your problem.

```
NSArray *array = @[@"aud1",@"aud2"];
    for (id obj in array) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            // Play each aud here
            NSLog(@"%@",obj);

        });
    }
```

Apple ref.: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/

Look this for more: https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
Player * play = [[Looper alloc] initWithFileNameQueue:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: audioFile, audioFile2, nil ]];
```

Player.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface Player : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
    AVAudioPlayer* play;
    NSArray* fileNameQueue;
    int index;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer* play;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* fileNameQueue;

- (id)initWithFileNameQueue:(NSArray*)queue;
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)play successfully:(BOOL)flag;
- (void)play:(int)i;
- (void)stop;

@end
```

Player.m

```
#import "Player.h"
@implementation Play
@synthesize player, fileNameQueue;

- (id)initWithFileNameQueue:(NSArray*)queue {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.fileNameQueue = queue;
        index = 0;
        [self play:index];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)play successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    if (index < fileNameQueue.count) {
        [self play:index];
    } else {
        //reached end of queue
    }
}

- (void)play:(int)i {
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[fileNameQueue objectAtIndex:i] ofType:nil]] error:nil];
    play.delegate = self;
    [play prepareToPlay];
    [play play];    
    index++;
}

- (void)stop {
    if (self.play.playing) [play stop];
}


@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Can you please tell me, What is Looper in your first line of code?

Comment: Your code is working well with sequential play. But as I explained in my question, I want to play audio simultaneously which is inside single array then instantly next array should play in the same way.